# Not able to link two HTMLs with each other

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, search, routes

I create a Movie page, where HTML 1 shows me all entries. This works. HTML 1 has a link per entry that should open HTML 2 and simply show the record's data. This works partially. The JSON is successfully sent back to the client, but the HTML is not used for that.

client: viewMovie.js

```
const resultDOM = document.getElementById("resultID");

const baseURL = "http://localhost:5000"

window.addEventListener("load", viewMovie)

async function viewMovie(e){
    try {
        e.preventDefault();
        let data = await fetch(`${baseURL}/movie/:id`)
        data = await data.json();
        console.log(data);
        resultDOM.innerHTML = `<tr>
        <td>${data.title}</td>
        <td>${data.genre}</td>
        <td>${data.publishDate}</td>
    </tr>`
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Client-side viewAllMovies.js

```
const moviesDOM = document.getElementById("moviesID");
const pageDOM = document.getElementById("pageID");

window.addEventListener("load", viewAllMovies)

const baseURL = "http://localhost:5000"


async function viewAllMovies(e){
    try {
        e.preventDefault();
        let data = await fetch(`${baseURL}/movie/showAllMovies`)
        data = await data.json();

        const countEntries = data.length;
        let pages = Math.ceil(countEntries/recordsPerPage);
        let content = [];

        for(i=1 ; i <= pages; i++){
            content.push(`<option value=${i}>${i}</option>`);
        }
        content = content.join("");
        pageDOM.innerHTML = content;

        data = data.map( item =>{
            return `<tr>
            <td>${item.title}</td>
            <td>${item.genre}</td>
            <td>${item.publishDate}</td>
            <td>${item.country}</td>
            <td>${item.description}</td>
            <td>${item.classification}</td>
            <td>${item.poster}</td>
            <td>${item.fsk}</td>
            <td>${item.rating}</td>
            <td>${item.like}</td>
            <td><a href="${baseURL}/movie/${item._id}">LINK</a></td>
        </tr>`
        })
        moviesDOM.innerHTML = data
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Routings:

app.js

```
app.use(express.static("assets/html"))
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/movie", movieRouter)
```

movie-router.js

```
router.route("/createMovie").post(createMovie);
router.route("/showAllMovies").get(viewAllMovies);
router.route("/:id").patch(updateMovie).get(viewMovie);
```

viewMovie-controller.js

```
const viewMovie = async (req,res)=>{
    try {
        const movie = req.params.id;
        const data = await Movie.findOne({_id:movie})
        console.log(data);
        res.status(200).json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYdGk.png)

I have no idea, why the id HTML is not shown.

Comment: where is the actual templated view? are you using ejs / pug / something else? https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: I am using vanilla HTML. No views at all. I want to get an understanding of the basics, before I move over to the view.

Comment: You are sending back `res.status(200).json(data);` a json data, but you should send html